# Search phone number with regex Java

Tags: java, regex

I want to find numbers like

```
(123).234.4567
(123)-234-4567
123.234.4567
123-456-4567
```

This digits represents US phone numbers. So they can be separated with -(dash) or .(dot) and must have 3 digits, followed by another 3 digits, followed by 4 more. And the first 3 digits can be fenced or not with brackets '()'.

and code is like below

```
 Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("^(\\(\\d{3}\\))|^\\d{3}[.-]?\\d{3}[.-]?\\d{4}$");
 Matcher matcher = regex.matcher("(425).882.8080 tel");
 while(matcher.find()){
        System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

But the result is :

```
(425)
```

What I am doing Wrong. I want to print (425).882.8080 at once.

Comment: What is the expected output?. What is it that you actually want to do?

Comment: I add more explanations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [**Back reference**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) to check for exact match.

> Backreferences match the same text as previously matched by a capturing group

```
          ^(\(\d{3}\)|\d{3})([.-])\d{3}\2\d{4}$
Capture 2nd group -----------^^^^      ^^-------- Same text as 2nd captured group
```

Groups are captured by enclosing it inside the parenthesis `(...)` and can be accessed by `\index`

Here is [online demo](http://regex101.com/r/bX6uD0/1)

**Note:** If you want to find substring in a string then remove `^` and `$` that are used for beginning and ending of the string respectively.

Patten explanation:

```
  (                        group and capture to \1:
    \(                       '('
    \d{3}                    digits (0-9) (3 times)
    \)                       ')'
   |                        OR
    \d{3}                    digits (0-9) (3 times)
  )                        end of \1

  (                        group and capture to \2:
    [.-]                     any character of: '.', '-'
  )                        end of \2

  \d{3}                    digits (0-9) (3 times)
  \2                       what was matched by capture \2
  \d{4}                    digits (0-9) (4 times)
```

---

Sample code:

```
String regex="(\\(\\d{3}\\)|\\d{3})([.-])\\d{3}\\2\\d{4}";

System.out.println("(123).234.4567".matches(regex)); // true
System.out.println("(123)-234-4567".matches(regex)); // true
System.out.println("123.234.4567".matches(regex));   // true
System.out.println("123-456-4567".matches(regex));   // true

System.out.println("(123)-234.4567".matches(regex)); // false
System.out.println("(123-234-4567".matches(regex));  // false
System.out.println("123.234-4567".matches(regex));   // false
System.out.println("123-456.4567".matches(regex));   // false
```

Sample code: (as per your's)

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher("(425).882.8080 tel");
while (matcher.find()) {
    String str = matcher.group();
    System.out.println(str);  // (425).882.8080
}
```

Comment: is the start and end patterns necessary?

Comment: Not needed if `String.matches()` method is used.

Comment: I remove ^$. Thanks user3218114

Answer (score 1):

You only have one matching group: `(\\(\\d{3}\\))`

Try

```
 Pattern.compile("^((?:\\(\\d{3}\\))|^\\d{3}[.-]?\\d{3}[.-]?\\d{4})");
```

this will provide you the whole matched number.

If you, instead, need all numbers separately you have to add multiple matching groups, like

```
     Pattern.compile("^(\\(\\d{3}\\))|^(\\d{3})[.-]?(\\d{3})[.-]?(\\d{4})");
```

Btw. by using `[.-]?` you will also match `1232344567` (without dots/dashes). To fix this, drop the `?` after `[.-]`.

An optimized version could be:

```
Pattern.compile("^((\\((\\d{3})\\)|(\\d{3}))[.-](\\d{3})[.-](\\d{4}))");
```

This way you get the whole matched number as well as all included nubmers separately.

Another point: your ininital regexp would also match `123.234-4567` If that's not desireable, anothe OR is needed for all cases.

E.g.

```
Pattern.compile("^((\\((\\d{3})\\)|((\\d{3})\\.(\\d{3})\\.(\\d{4})|(\\d{3})-(\\d{3})-(\\d{4})))");
```

Updated for you last edit:

```
Pattern.compile("^((?:\\(\\d{3}\\)|\\d{3})(?:\\.\\d{3}\\.\\d{4}|\\d{3}-\\d{3}-\\d{4}))");
```

Comment: The non-capturing group in the first regex seems rather pointless. It could be just `^(\(\d{3}\)|^\d{3}[.-]?\d{3}[.-]?\d{4})$`.

Comment: Yeah, I just wanted to keep as much of the original regexp to point out what has to be improved.

Comment: I tried with the first one but nothing happends not match anything.

Comment: Drop the `$` at the end as you don't want to match the whole string. maybe also the `^` needs to be dropped if you want to match telefon numbers in some other string.

Comment: I droped it but the result is the same

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to put start and end anchors in your regex if the phone number would appears anywhere on the input.

```
\d{3}([.-])?\d{3}\1?\d{4}|\(\d{3}\)([.-])?\d{3}\2?\d{4}
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/iA1yO5/9)

Java regex would be,

```
"\\d{3}([.-])?\\d{3}\\1?\\d{4}|\\(\\d{3}\\)([.-])?\\d{3}\\2?\\d{4}"
```

**Example:**

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\\d{3}([.-])?\\d{3}\\1?\\d{4}|\\(\\d{3}\\)([.-])?\\d{3}\\2?\\d{4}");
 Matcher matcher = regex.matcher("(425).882.8080 tel");
 while(matcher.find()){
        System.out.println(matcher.group());
} // (425).882.8080
```

Comment: But then this will match things like `(123-123-1234` and `123).123.1234` which *might* not be desirable.

Comment: It still matches `123.123-1234`